# database unconfirmed deadlock t-sql 2005

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2005

For instance, there exists table A and table B, and i need to process an update in A and then B and I decide to table lock both them during use (as demanded by my architect). Simultaneously, another procedure is called which table locks B, then locks A.

Will this transaction complete? I have a feeling its a deadlock, quite sure of it as it's not releasing any resources...

Comment: are these locks table locks or can they be page or row locks

Comment: Just curious why are you taking table lock?You will keep lots of user out by taking table lock..Also it will increase the chance of deadlock.Can you take row level or page level locks?

Comment: yeah i raised that point about row/page level locks with my architect...but clients and management want it that way so :\

Comment: Good luck..Once system is in prod..You can be superstar if you suggest this to fix all the deadlocks and blocking issue faced by your end users..BTW, are you using snapshot isolation level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a possible deadlock.

The deadlock scenario is

Your task locks A
Other task locks B

then 
Your task tries to lock B but it can't as you have the lock
and 
other task tries to lock A but it can't as you have it.

So one of these tasks has to fail/rollback so the other can complete. Depending on RDBMS used the db will choose one of these to terminate.

Often the solution is for a guideline that you must lock resources in the same order in all processes usually this has to be manualy enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This approach will end in a classic cyclic deadlock as mentioned [here](http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/06/cyclic-deadlock/)

Using TABLE level lock for an update is an Overkill. What is the rationale behind doing this ? If you have the correct indexes, locks will be acquired at the key level, which helps multiple processes concurrently access the tables in question.

Still it is a best practice to access the tables in the same order when possible.